# ¿Cómo añadir Input de tipo time en gvNIX?

Tags: spring, spring-roo, gvnix

Necesitaría poder añadir un campo de tipo time con gvNIX... he visto que existe el tagx datetime, pero este no me permite seleccionar las horas....

Estoy utilizando la versión 1.4.1 de gvNIX

Comment: bienvenido a es.stackoverflow quizas le interese leer esto  http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esta funcionalidad ha sido incluida en [gvNIX 1.5.1 RC3](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) .
Para añadir un campo de tipo hora debes modificar el valor de la anotación [DateTimeFormat](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) del campo *Date* desde la clase de su entidad y añadir el patrón de hora que se va a utilizar. Por ejemplo:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="HH:mm")
private Calendar schedule;
```

Será necesario reabrir la consola de gvNIX para que se apliquen estos cambios en el proyecto.
De este modo se mostrará el input de tipo *time* para seleccionar una hora, el cual podrás personalizar desde la vista jspx.

Comment: Ahora el formato del campo en la vista es correcto, pero falla al hacer la conversión de String a Calendar:  
`Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Calendar for property auditLastUpdate; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Calendar for value 06:45; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "06:45" is malformed at ":45"`

Comment: He editado mi respuesta para añadir correctamente un campo de tipo hora teniendo en cuenta este problema.

Comment: Funciona correctamente gracias!